# Fmod does not work as expected(c programming)

Tags: c, math.h, fmod

(the problem is caused by me and has been solved ,greetings from the newbie)I apologize to everyone, my function type was integer i just realized it, I opened it because I worked for hours, I have to delete it).
I am using gcc 9.3.0 version and standard settings. In the code in the example, I am getting 7 while waiting to get output 7.14. What could be the reason for this?(im using gcc main.c -lm -o main when compiling,what I'm trying to do is print as an integer if the double number is equal to integer, otherwise print it as a double,sorry for the adjustments, this is the last and proper version)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int try(double a);

int main() {
  double b = 7.14;
  double x;
  double temp;

  x = try(b);

  if (fmod(x, 1) == 0.0) {  // print 7 in this function
    temp = x;
    printf("%d", (int)temp);
  } 
   else if (fmod(x, 1) != 0.0) {
    printf("%f", x);
  }

  return 0;
}

int try(double a) {
  if (fmod(a, 1) != 0.0) {
    printf("%lf", a);  // print 7.14 in this function
  } else if (fmod(a, 1) == 0.0) {
    printf("%d", (int)a);
  }

  return a + 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce; prints out 7.140000 for me.

Comment: Also, it's a bad idea to compare a double with ==.  Instead use <= delta where delta is some small value.

Comment: I use the double value returned from the other function instead of x, when I print it in the other function, it prints it as 7.14 but when i do this in main function it print 7.0.I immediately edit the question to avoid confusion

Comment: I get 7.140000 with gcc 9.3.0. https://wandbox.org/permlink/xipjKx9PUx6fgox0 Same after the edit: https://wandbox.org/permlink/UMHioIMbBkvawokq

Comment: I believe the printf format specifier for `double` should be just `%f` and not `%lf`.  (It's different from scanf.)  Does that change anything?

Comment: Older compilers have trouble printing with `"%lf"`.  Try `"%f"`.

Comment: user15465584, " I am getting 7 " --> Did you mean `"7.000000"`, `"7"` or something else?

Comment: I couldn't edit the final version right away due to internet problem. I'm sorry. No, it only prints 7 .

Comment: Hmmm `try` is a reserved word in other languages, perhaps another word?  Or the code posted is not the true code.  Review the cut/paste  and maybe improve format..

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. I'm reverting your last change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)

Got the result 7.140000

Some code-format and debug output.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double func_try(double a) { return a + 0; }

int main() {
  double b = 7.14;
  double x;
  x = func_try(b);

  printf("%lf\n", fmod(x, 1));

  if (fmod(x, 1) != 0.0) {
    printf("%lf", x);
  } else if (fmod(x, 1) == 0.0) {
    printf("%d", (int)x);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
$gcc main.c -lm -o main

$./main
0.140000
7.140000
```

Answer (score 0):

`fmod(7.14, 1) = 0.14`, thus it hit the first `if` and print `7.14`.

> Compute remainder of division
>
> Returns the floating-point remainder of numer/denom (rounded towards zero):
>
> fmod = numer - tquot * denom
>
> Where tquot is the truncated (i.e., rounded towards zero) result of: numer/denom.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/

Comment: OP says they're getting 7, not 7.14, though.